# Uiswitch on/off

Tags: objective-c, xcode

m new to objective-c, i have made a application of login page in which i have used UISwitch to remember d login details if switch is in on mode. i have done with to remember the login details but problem is that how to use the switch on/off condition. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 18):

The easiest solution of all :)

```
if (switchValue.on){
    //Remember Login Details
}
else{
    //Code something else
}
```

Comment: How am I able to add a value to the switch?

Answer (score 7):

You would add a conditional statement somewhere in your code depending on the switch's `on` property. Let's say, for example, that you remember login details in a method called `rememberLoginDetails`. What you would do is, when some action is triggered (the user leaves the login page, for example):

```
if([yourSwitch isOn]) {
    [self rememberLoginDetails];
} else {
    // Do nothing - switch is not on.
}
```

The important method here is the `isOn` method for the UISwitch `yourSwitch`. `isOn` is the getter for the switch's `on` property, which is a `BOOL` property containing `YES` if the switch is on, and `NO` if it is not.

For more information, you can see the [UISwitch class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically the [part about `isOn`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006784-CH3-SW5).

Comment: hi tim, i have used your code..but d problem is remain same. it is remembering d details in off condition too.

Comment: In that case, it would help if you could edit your original question to include the code you're using.

Comment: @Harita: I had the same problem.. I tried using a == TRUE afterwards and it still did not work. Then I went into interface builder, connected the switch to my IBOutlet var, and it worked :]

Comment: Older iPhones does not recognise the on/off state of the UISwitch.  You need to have a boolean value which you need to change when user on/off the switch.

Comment: @ThE uSeFuL: I don't know what you mean - the UISwitch component and its `on` property have existed since iOS 2.0, when the SDK was first available. Do you perhaps mean the hardware mute switch? We're talking about the UISwitch graphical component.

Comment: @Tim, then for some strange reason 'on' property didn't work for me in the iPhone 3GS (OS 4.2.1) I tested.  But when tested in a latest iOS version it worked.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remember the login details just the moment where the user TURN ON the switch, you can done it by create an Action.

```
- (IBAction)yourSwitch:(id)sender {
    if([sender isOn]){
        //do your stuff here
    }else{
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code needs to be this:

```
if([yourSwitch isOn] == YES) {
    [self rememberLoginDetails];
} else {
    // Do nothing - switch is not on.
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. If value of the return is a BOOL, then you do not need to use a comparison operator, as the "if" operates on a BOOL (if(TRUE) do stuff; else do other stuff;). So, as long as [yourSwitch isOn] returns YES (or NO), the "if" will traverse correctly. This code here actually has to make more calls, making it slower (only by a few millisecs, but still).

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution, if your UISwitch is in a tableView

1 add this code in "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:" method

```
[switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

2 add this method

```
- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *switchControl = sender;
    NSLog( @"The switch is %@", switchControl.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(switchValue.isOn){
    [switchValue setOn:NO];
} else {
   [switchValue setOn:YES];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is another solution for that question.

```
if (switchValue.on == YES)
{
    // Code...
}
else
{
    // Other code... 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem, i had the name of the UISwitch = Selected

i changed it to another name and it worked.